# why my intel core i3-2310M CPU @ 2.10 Ghz become so hot?

Tags: laptop, fan, temperature, core

i use Hp Pavilion g4 with intel core i3-2310M CPU @ 2.10 Ghz. I've checked my laptop and the core temperature is among ~75°C and also my fan is working so hard all the time even if I don't use it (in idle mode). This condition just happened 3 days ago (until now). Is that any solution of my problem? Help me please (A.S.A.P). I'm afraid that I can't use my laptop for do my university tasks :( Thank you.

Comment: You can use a support ventilated for laptop like this -> http://media.ldlc.com/ld3/300/2008/LD0000782611.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I have actually owned the laptop you are talking about and I have to say they are very well known for having ramped up fan speeds due to heat (My laptop actually died because of over heating).

It might be worth taking it apart and trying to get any dust you can out of the heat sinks. Once enough dust gets caked in them they become very inefficient.

If you are unsure on taking it apart you can 1. Watch a YouTube video on your specific laptop (What I did the first time). Or 2. Pay for it to be sent for repair somewhere and they will carry out the task for you.

Also as advised try getting a laptop stand and also not constantly using it on a bed for example where the vents don't have much room to breath.

Hope this helps :)